# Why does the java -Xmx not working?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux out of memory on VPS](https://serverfault.com/questions/452042/linux-out-of-memory-on-vps)

In my Ubuntu 11.10 VPS, Before I run the jar file:

```
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           256          5        250          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:          5        250
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Run a jar file that limited to maximum of **32M** memory:

```
java -Xms8m -Xmx32m -jar ./my.jar
```

Now the memory state as follows:

```
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           256        155        100          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:        155        100
Swap:            0          0          0
```

This jar occupied **150M** memory.

And I can't run any other java command:

```
# java -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

# java -Xmx8m -version  
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

I want to know why the **-Xmx** parameter does not take effect?

How can I limit the jar file using the memory?

Answer (score 3):

The `-Xmx` parameter defines the heap size, aka the memory you can allocate in the program. The `java` binary and the loaded `jar` file each needs additional space, naturally.

Answer (score 1):

It's not Java who used up all the memory, the system also consumes RAM to cache data (look at the cache output from `free -m` and `top`)

You're running Java (BLOATED software) on a 256MB RAM VPS **without swap**. Are you really *really* sure you want to go down this path?

Comment: I just run the java, then free-m, Not running other programs,and I got a crash log `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 32756 bytes for ChunkPool::allocate. Out of swap space?`

Comment: Yes - like your `free -m` pointed out, the VPS has NO swap space at all, which is extremely silly. Call your VPS provider.

Comment: Thanks @pauska ,You're right, But can I turn off java to use the swap?